# Getting the Absolute Path of the current class in eclipse (Resource Location of a class)

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to get the absolute path of the class I am working on.

I have tried doing this:

```
Class currentClass = new Object() {
    }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
    System.out.println(currentClass);
    System.out.println(" PATH IS: " + currentClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
    System.out.println("Present Project Directory : " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

BUT I am getting this kind of output:
PATH IS: file:/C:/Users/jean/eclipse-workspace/AutoCompile/bin/
Present Project Directory : C:\Users\jean\eclipse-workspace\MyProject

I want to get a result like this:
C:\Users\jean\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\src\com\school\demo\Locator.java

Comment: The bytecode (`.class`) does not know about its source (`.java`) and there might be more than one source folders. As a workaround, you can use the output folder and replace `/bin/` with `/src/` plus the qualified name (replace `.` with `/`) and the extension `.java` (but you have to take care about inner classes and files defining multiple classes).

Comment: This information is of little use on its own. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @nitind i am trying to create a plugin that compile the active class in eclipse. so i need to get its location (with package) not only the project location